# 2 tabstop or 4 tabstop for Python

Tags: python, vim

I am currently using 4 space tabstops in Vim.
A work colleague says i should have it as 2 and not to indent 4 spaces in Python.
I understand why 2 spaces is better, but PEP8 says to have 4 spaces.
What is the better practise?

(I could set my tabstop to 2 and then tab twice)

Comment: 2 spaces is evil and your soul will be consumed. 4 spaces is familiar to everyone and its easier to spot code blocks that way. Save yourself! Sadly its too late for your colleague, he will not be mourned.

Comment: Here's what you do: (1) Install `black` as a commit-hook, so all code in your repo ends up with 4 spaces a God and Guido intended. (2) Show your colleague how to install `yapf`, configure it however he wants, and set up his editor to `yapf` every Python file on open. Now he'll see everything with 2 spaces, and can edit things the way he prefers, and nobody else will have to deal with the horror. People who like 2 spaces are really no different from people who like to disable syntax coloring and view everything in green on black so they can feel OG—let them, as long as it doesn't affect you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PEP8 is pretty clear:

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Even the [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Indentation), who uses two spaces in their Java Style Guide, says:

> Indent your code blocks with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Check the python vim [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim), within your `.vimrc` you could use:

```
" Python ident
au FileType python set ts=8 sts=4 et sw=4 smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
```

or while editing:

```
:set tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
```

It follows [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) style guide (**Use 4 spaces per indentation level.**)